# Create selection change event in custom control using dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have used a custom control in wpf from [Source code for multiselect](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/multi-select-combobox-in-wpf/). that control is a multiselect combobox with checkbox. but selection changed event is not present in that.I am trying to create a selection changed event using DependencyProperty. I am new to WPF. I don't know how to use DependencyProperty for creating events.  Can Anyone tell me how to create selection change event in that control.
[Combobox image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcfr1.png)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752288(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: have a look here as well http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/routed-events/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a RoutedEvent. 
   [Create a custom routed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752288(v=vs.100).aspx)

But better yet you can use an existing routed event from the selector class called [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Raising the selection changed event from your code: **psedo code since i am not near vs.**

```
 SelectionChangedEventArgs args = new SelectionChangedEventArgs();
 args.AddedItem.add(... how ever is checked ..);
 args.RemovedItem.add(... how ever was unchecked ..);  
 this.RaiseEvent(args); // this your control.
```